# fillStyle on array [HTML5 Canvas]

Tags: html, canvas

I have this:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

....
....

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
```

The real thing I need to change, is the shapes of a tetris game. They're written like this:

```
var shapes = [
[ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],

[ 1, 1, 1, 0,
  1 ],

[ 1, 1, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1 ],

[ 1, 1, 0, 0,
  1, 1 ],

[ 1, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 1 ],

[ 0, 1, 1, 0,
  1, 1 ],

[ 0, 1, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 1 ]
];
```

I would like to change the color of the first one, which is [1,1,1,1] or shapes[0], but none of what I've tried works.
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'; works, but it changes the color of all the objects.

Live version can be viewed here:

http://harlem-shake-it.com/tetris/

Comment: I assume you want each shape to have a different color.  It looks like you've coded your shapes to get merged into the board after they have fallen.  To color each shape differently, you'll have to be sure each "finished" block on the board is assigned it shape's color. That way when you draw "finished" blocks you can set the appropriate fillcolor.

Answer (score 0):

From this code, I assume you only want the current object to be blue?

```
for (var y = 0; y < 4; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {
        if (current[y][x]) {
            ctx.fillStyle = '#0068ff';
            drawBlock(currentX + x,currentY + y);
        }
    }
}
```

If that's the case, you'll need to first save the current canvas state with `ctx.save();`, use the fillStyle, draw the block, and then `ctx.restore();`. This should allow you to fill your blocks with multiple colors, if you want. Or, in this case, have the fallen blocks be rendered black.

You [should also declare a doctype](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype): `<!doctype html>`. And [the `<center>` tag is deprecated.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp) You should use `text-align: center;` in CSS moving forward, or `margin: 0 auto;` depending on what you're styling.

Comment: Like it is now? Go check it out: http://harlem-shake-it.com/tetris/js/tetris.js
Search for ctx.restore

Comment: More like this in the render() function: 
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#0068ff';
    drawBlock(currentX + x,currentY + y);
    ctx.restore();

Comment: Since you're not actually drawing any blocks where you put the save/restore, their color information is never saved. You'll have to add information that knows what the block is and can extract its color each time inside the render function. So instead of doing an iteration over the whole board and redrawing it, just change the final draw state of the object once it falls and use a second canvas to do the movement or else only clear falling shape.

Comment: I've tried the ctx.save() stuff inside render(), but it doesn't seem like it's working.
Check the code: http://harlem-shake-it.com/tetris/js/tetris.js

Please reply with an answer for proper formatting :)

Comment: This worked for how your code is set up. You can remove the save/restore from newShape(), since it doesn't do anything there. Right now, you should see all placed blocks rendered in black, and all live blocks rendered in blue. If you want the placed blocks to be rendered as their set color, you'll have to rethink how you currently draw things in render(). Right now, you erase everything and redraw based on board. You'll need to add an object to board that contains the color the square should be, using your current implementation, and then extract that color in before you draw that square.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.
I would like to give each object/shape a color. For example, the long .... should be blue, while .:. should be red, z should be orange and so on. They shouldn't all be blue.

Comment: I understood. In your current implementation, the active (falling) brick is always blue. In order to make the bricks not be all black once they fall to the bottom, you'll have to extend board, which is storing all the squares on the screen, regardless of shape, and attach a color to it, either by doing board[x][y][color] or something else. And then when you cycle through the board in render(), you'll have to ctx.save(); ctx.fillStyle = board[x][y][color]; draw the board; ctx.restore();. Right now, no color information from shapes[] is being saved in the canvas context.

Comment: The active falling brick is always blue. Correct. Those are the ones I need to change the colors of, not the ones at the bottom.

Comment: OK. Inside newObject(), you'll need to store objects[id][0] (the color of the shape) in a global variable that you then reference in render() where '#0068ff' is now.